# Angularjs module requires won't work

Tags: angularjs, angular-leaflet-directive

I have this code :

```
var app = angular.module("malocFeApp",['leaflet-directive']);
app.controller('MainCtrl',[ "$scope", function($scope) {  }]);
```

It prevent the template to show up.

When I remove the requires the template show up:

```
var app = angular.module("malocFeApp");
app.controller('MainCtrl',[ "$scope", function($scope) {  }]);
```

Why did the requires prevent the module to work correctly?

Comment: you talking about require.js?

Comment: No I talk about second argument of angular.Module [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module)

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure you have the angular leaflet.js script referenced in your HTML
2. Make sure it is referenced after angular.js?
3. Check your JavaScript console output (F12 in your browser) for errors regarding dependency injection errors

Comment: All is correct because when I do this : `app.requires.push('leaflet-directive')`, everythings works fine. But it should be like that! And I have no error

Comment: Please put these things as comment.It is not an anwer

Comment: They are a list of possible solutions. I'll reword

Comment: This is plunker for my code : (https://plnkr.co/edit/sMvcl1pdBl558x0cVlmJ?p=preview)